# Objective-C blocks and data execution

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks

When I'm reading the apple iOS Developer Guide, it explains me a bit about using Blocks (For use with GCD). It should pass some "snippit of code" into a objective-c object, and pass it to the other thread so it can be executed there. Wouldn't make the use of this exremely vulnarible to viruses and such? (data execution). Or am I missing some point here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - you can think of this 'code snippet' as a compiled, private, hidden function declared within your function (method…). IOW, it's as dangerous as any compiled function in your binary.

Answer (score 3):

Even when you use `^blocks`, your code is still pre-compiled.
I would say it's not more vulnerable then the rest of the "weak-linked" objective-c stuff.

The `^block` is more something in the compiler / pre-compiler stage. I would say the resulting binary does not look much different (from a security perspective) then without blocks.